# React Material UI Button onclick not working (The 3rd parameter is expected to be the HTML form element or the style selector of form )

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem about clicking Button provided by Material UI to send information as an email.

When I click the button, I got this kind of error message shown below.

```
The 3rd parameter is expected to be the HTML form element or the style selector of form
```

How can I fix it?

Here are my code snippets shown below.

Contact Component

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ... The usage of EMAILJS 
}

<Grid item xs={12} className="p_30">
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                    <TextField fullWidth name="name" label="Name" onChange={handleName}/>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                    <TextField fullWidth name="email" label="E-mail" onChange={handleEmail}/>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <TextField fullWidth name="message" label="Message" multiline minRows={4} onChange={handleMessage}/>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <CustomButton text={"Submit"} submitfunction={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}/>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
          </Grid>
```

CustomButton Component

```
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

const CustomButton = ({ text, icon, submitfunction }) => {
  return (
    <Button
      className="site_btn"
      onClick={submitfunction}
      endIcon={
        icon ? (
          <div className="icon_container">
              {icon}
          </div>
        ) : null
      }
    >
      <span className="button_text">{text}</span>
    </Button>
  );
};

export default CustomButton;
```

Comment: Can you provide full code with codesandbox link?

Comment: I would assume that the error message  comes from EMAILJS, and not from Material UI ?